# Undefined reference to QAbstractListModel::postion

Tags: qt, qt5.4, qabstractlistmodel

I'm getting this error when implementing `QAbstractListModel`.

```
./debug\moc_ObjectModel.o:moc_ObjectModel.cpp:(.rdata$_ZTV12ObjectModel[__ZTV12ObjectModel]+0x38): undefined reference to `QAbstractListModel::position(int, int, QModelIndex const&) const'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

**Building the project was successful before I add insert and remove method to my model.**

First, I add the insert and remove method but forgot to call begin* and end* method, so I got an error when rebuilding the project.

After that, I add begin* and end*  as stated in the docs. But, when I build the project, I'm getting the error stated above. Then, I remove the insert and remove method and the error still remains.

**I have tried to delete the build directory of the project, clean, run qmake, and then build the project but it was no good.**

**ObjectModel.h**

```
#ifndef OBJECTMODEL_H
#define OBJECTMODEL_H

#include "ProjectCoreGlobal.h"
#include "Data/MyObject.h"

#include <QAbstractListModel>

class PROJECTCORESHARED_EXPORT ObjectModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit ObjectModel(QObject *parent = 0);

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &position, int role) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;

    // void insertObject(MyObject *object);
    // void removeObject(int position);

    MyObjectList objects() const;

    MyObject *objectById(const int &id);
    MyObject *objectByName(const QString &name);

private:
    MyObjectList mObjects;
};

#endif // OBJECTMODEL_H
```

**ObjectModel.cpp**

```
#include "ObjectModel.h"

ObjectModel::ObjectModel(QObject *parent) :
    QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

int ObjectModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
{
    if (parent.isValid())
        return 0;
    else
        return mObjects.size();
}

QVariant ObjectModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
        return QVariant();

    MyObject *obj = mObjects.at(index.row());

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole) {
        return obj->name();
    }

    return QVariant();
}

// void ObjectModel::insertObject(MyObject *object)
// {
//    beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), mObjects.count(), mObjects.count());
//    mObjects.append(object);
//    endInsertRows();
// }

// void ObjectModel::removeObject(int position)
// {
//     beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), position, position);
//     mObjects.removeAt(position);
//     endRemoveRows();
// }

MyObjectList ObjectModel::objects() const
{
    return mObjects;
}

MyObject *ObjectModel::objectById(const int &id)
{
    foreach (MyObject *obj, mObjects)
    {
        if (obj->id() == id)
        {
            return obj;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}

MyObject *ObjectModel::objectByNme(const QString &name)
{
    foreach (MyObject *obj, mObjects)
    {
        if (obj->name() == name)
        {
            return object;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any position(...) function in the documentation ?

Comment: Yeah. I don't know why I'm having this error or is this a bug of the IDE? BTW, I use QtCreator 3.3.1.

Comment: IDEs don't do linking, linkers do. Add the code of ObjectModel. Do you have any weird defines or typedefs before the QAbstractListModel include?

Comment: I have a typedef from MyObject header file which is included in ObjectModel header file. `typedef QList<MyObject *> MyObjectList`. Will be posting my code.

Comment: @Martin, second that, never saw such. iSa, if you use Qt Creator make sure to delete the correct build folder, it can be different if shadow build is checked in the project settings.

Comment: Try to clean all and rebuild project.

Comment: Btw. there is a typo in `ObjectModel::objectByNme`. I hope that is not in your real code. It should produce a different error message ...

Comment: Please post `moc_ObjectModel.h` from your build directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only `QAbstractListModel` class member that matches the signature from the error message is `QAbstractListModel::index`.

It most certainly means that there is a `#define index position` somewhere before the include for that class, either in the 2 headers files, or in the project settings (`DEFINES += index=position` in the .pro file).

Try putting `#include <QAbstractListModel>` first in ObjectModel.h.

You should also check that the Qt header file for the `QAbstractListModel` class wasn't inadvertently modified by a search/replace in the wrong window (compare with the original class [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.h?h=5.4.2#n445)).

Comment: Tried to put `#include <QAbstractListModel>` first but no luck. Checked all the header files included and .pro file, but there's no `#define index position`.

Comment: @iSa Try to add a line `#define index something` at the beginning of `objectmodel.h`, if index is actually defined, gcc should generate a warning with the location of the other definition. If there isn't any warning, you should check that the Qt header file for the ` QAbstractListModel` class wasn't inadvertently modified by a search/replace in the wrong window (compare with the original class [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/itemmodels/qabstractitemmodel.h?h=5.4.2#n445)).

Comment: I have checked the `qabstractitemmodel.h` file located in `QtInstallFolder\5.4\mingw491_32\include\QtCore`. As you have said, the `QAbstractListModel::index` was being replaced by `QAbstractListModel::position`. Renamed it back to `QAbstractListModel::index` and "Thank You", I was able to build my project.